# Booleans and Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I am working on an app that uses Firebase database to store some Booleans that looks similar to this

```
"TEST" : {
"TEST" : {
  "Current_job" : {
    "important_job" : true,
    "washed" : true
  },
  "colour" : "test",
  "date" : "test",
  "doors" : "test",
  "enginesize" : "test",
  "fuel" : "test",
  "lotnumber" : "test",
  "manufacturer" : "test",
  "model" : "test",
  "reg" : "TEST"
}
```

I activate them  using check-boxes with in my app. When the check box is ticked it pushes the Boolean true to my database, and false un-ticked.

I'd like to call these Boolean back in another activity and use them in a similar way you would use Shared preference.

So I've copied from Frank's answer below but I get an null pointer error.

```
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Boolean a,b,c,d;
        a = valueSnapshot.child("important_job").getValue(Boolean.class);
```

This is where the null pointer error is

```
        if (a){
            CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cbimportant);
            cb1.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cbimportant);
            cb1.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: handling booleans works **exactly** the same as strings and ints. Are you sure you are actually working with arrays here? The three boolean values do not seem to be suited to be in an array.

Comment: Is it not called an array when there is a group of a booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is a very specific data structure. For example an array of the three names you have would be stored like this in JSON/Firebase:

```
["washed", "polished", "waxed"]
```

As you probably noticed, this means you've lost your boolean value. That's because the elements in an array are unnamed.

What you show is more likely to be a so-called associative map, or just key-value-pairs. Which is stored like this in JSON/Firebase:

```
{
  "washed": true,
  "polished": false,
  "waxed": false
}
```

Either way, it's really much easier to help if you show your actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

If you're looking to get both the keys and the values out of this, you attach a listener to the node above it and loop over the children of the snapshot like this:

```
Database currentJobRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CurrentJob");
currentJobRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(valueSnapshot.getKey()); // prints "washed", "published", "waxed"
      System.out.println(valueSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)); prints true, false, false
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen thanks for the help pal can you check my question ive updated the code cheerz

Comment: @Peter Haddad why has my question been put on hold? cheerz pal